# WCF duplex with DHCP?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm using a duplex WCF contract in this chat-like application that i have running. (obviously not really a chat, but for the interest of thinking about it you can assume it's similar enough).

the problem is that many of the clients that talk over this contract are running dhcp, and there's not really anything i can do about this.

What's the best way to handle duplex communication with dhcp? I found a setting `<compositeDuplex clientBaseAddress="Uri"/>` which means i could update this value at runtime.... seems a bit kludgy.

Update
I found that in my WCF server logs, part of the problem is that it was putting hostname in the response address. what am i doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: I used WCF for about a month, thinking it was a magic solution to networking problems. I was wrong. I ended up using the Sockets API included in .NET (System.Net.Sockets); saved quite a bit of trouble too, plus it's cross-platform (via Mono).

Comment: What does DHCP have to do with your problem?

Comment: @John, the problem seems to be that the server needs to open a port on the client, but when the client connects, it's only providing its hostname, not its full ip address to respond to.

Comment: hopefully, the hostname will resolve to the correct IP address. Again, DHCP has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @John I think you're right. it just seemed to be that when using DHCP seemed to be the only thing that caused the particular failure we had. Something else must have been at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be blunt, the first thing that you're doing wrong is using DualHttpBinding to do duplex. That whole binding is a giant kludge and is prone to problems like this (and firewalls, oh god firewalls).

If you were to use something like net.tcp instead then the clients establish a single bidirectional connection to the server instead of needing two connections, and thus the server doesn't care if the client is on DHCP anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your candidness. Moving away from the http transports completely cleared up our problems. Next problem became that since we are using a custom binding, the `<tcpTransport>` element does not support the maxReceivedMessageSize in configuration, so altering the MessageEncodingBindingElment constructor for our custom encoding fixed this.